# Another Dynamic table that is not working (Search Engine)

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

Hello another problem with php im not sure why its not working but here is the code:

```
        <?php include 'db.inc.php';function search_results($keywords){$returned_results = array();
$where = "";

$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
$total_keywords = count($keywords);


foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
    $where .="`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1 )){
        $where .= " AND ";
    }
}

$results = "SELECT `document_name` ,LEFT(`first_paragraph`,70) as `first_paragraph` FROM `documents` WHERE $where ";
$results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results) : 0 ;
if ($results_num == 0){
    return false;
}else {

    while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $returned_results[] = array(
                'title' => $results_row['document_name'],
                'description' => $results_row['first_paragraph']
    );
}

return $returned_results;


}
}

?>
```

Im trying at the moment to make it with PDO but im not sure how..
im not sure if that is the problem but i dont get anything from mysql
Thx for your time!

Comment: Are you connecting to your db.inc.php file?  I always have mine like this: include_once ('db.inc.php');

Comment: What errors do you get - specifically are you getting MySQL errors?

Comment: Like many programmers, he's not checking if mysql_query()` returns FALSE.  If it does, check `mysql_error()`.

Comment: When i write something in the form i get "Your Search for "Keyword" returned no results wich means that $results_num == 0 but i cant find why. Thx for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put your entire WHERE condition in single quotes right now you are doing something like this:

```
SELECT document_name ,LEFT(first_paragraph,70) as first_paragraph FROM documents WHERE '`keywords` LIKE '%keyword%''
```

It should just be:

```
SELECT document_name ,LEFT(first_paragraph,70) as first_paragraph FROM documents WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%keyword%'
```

You would have easily been able to spot this with some basic debugging.

- Always write code to capture and log database errors (you have no such code)
- If the database error doesn't tell you what you want, log the query that you are trying to run and try to run it on the database directly.

Finally, I don't see any PDO here at all, you are using `mysql_*` functoins which are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: i wanted to make it pdo but im not sure how. i dont understand what you mean single quote? i add all the select inside results and with the $where i can add many AND so it can search more than 1 keywords..

Comment: with pdo i try this but im not sure if it accepts array..    
    $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT document_name,first_paragraph');
 $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'table');
 while($obj = $STH->fetch()) {
     $returned_results[] = array(
     'title' => $results_row['document_name'],
     'description' => $results_row['first_paragraph']

Comment: @AntMar It seems you have removed the single quotes around `$where` in your query which was originally shown in the question.  That should hopefully solve the query issue.

Comment: nope nothing still not working and i dont know why.. i changed the query with 100 different ways and its not working... i dont know what to do... im 100% sure its the query.

Comment: Anywhere else i can get ideas how to make a search engine at my website? cause i dont know what else to do... its just not working :(